# Latest Rows From Dataset Ordered By Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Hope someone can help as I'm really struggling with this.
I have a dataset that contains Id, PackageName, PostName, DatePosted, DateDelivered.
This dataset is constantly updating in realtime with new data, however the PackageName and PostName are not unique.

I'm trying to find a way of selecting rows where if the Difference in time between the DatePosted and DateDelivered is greater than a certain value, it will return data.

The problem is, the package might have two entries for DatePosted and DateDelivered, which means that the package will have actually been delivered and is no longer late, in which case, I don't want to report on this time difference any more.
However, because there is an entry in the table where this package *was* late, it's reporting on the package being late, which I don't want to happen.

I can't find a way to only report on the package being late if it's the last (max(DatePosted)) in the table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 SELECT    
   'Package Delayed',    
   dd.PackageName,  
   dd.PostName,  
   Max(datediff(ss,dd.DatePosted,isnull(dd.DateDelivered,GETDATE()))) as PackageDelay ,  
   @@SERVERNAME as SentFrom
 FROM       DeliveryDetails as dd 
 inner join dbo.AlertTable as at with (NOLOCK) on dd.PackageName = dd.PackageName  
 and  datediff(ss,dd.DatePosted,isnull(dd.DateDelivered,GETDATE())) >= at.DeliveryThreshold  
 WHERE at.NextAlert < GETDATE()  
 AND at.Active = 1  
 GROUP BY  
 at.SNO,  
 at.AlertEmail,  
 dd.PackageName,  
 dd.PostName
```

This gives me the result if the package was ever delayed, but I only want a result if the latest package sent is delayed.

Can anyone help, I just can't figure out how to do it?

Comment: can you please provide the table structure, sample data and expected output to help visualise the issue ?

Comment: Could you add one more condition in the where clause to get the latest rows only as - 
`WHERE at.NextAlert < GETDATE()  
 AND at.Active = 1 
and dd.DatePosted = ( SELECT MAX(DatePosted) FROM DeliveryDetails  a WHERE a.PackageName = dd.PacakgeName and datediff(ss,a.DatePosted,isnull(a.DateDelivered,GETDATE())) >= at.DeliveryThreshold  )`

Comment: The where condition only applies to rows before aggregation. They would want the condition in the having clause. By adding it in the where clause, they will eliminate only the rows recorded before delivery, successfully eliminating the row with the delivered data. However, the rows before the delivery will still exist and now appear as if it never delivered

Answer (score 0):

Applying the filter to your WHERE clause only helps each row of data before the aggregate. Adding a [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause applies to the aggregate. Try adding a MAX() column to that delivery date, the aggregate will be null if there is no delivery date. Then add a HAVING clause to eliminate the delivered packages:

```
 SELECT    
   'Package Delayed',    
   dd.PackageName,  
   dd.PostName,  
   Max(datediff(ss,dd.DatePosted,isnull(dd.DateDelivered,GETDATE()))) as PackageDelay ,  
   MAX(DateDelivered) AS DateLastDelivered, 
   @@SERVERNAME as SentFrom
 FROM DeliveryDetails as dd 
 inner join dbo.AlertTable as at with (NOLOCK) on dd.PackageName = dd.PackageName  
 and  datediff(ss,dd.DatePosted,isnull(dd.DateDelivered,GETDATE())) >= at.DeliveryThreshold  
 WHERE at.NextAlert < GETDATE()  
 AND at.Active = 1  
 GROUP BY  
 at.SNO,  
 at.AlertEmail,  
 dd.PackageName,  
 dd.PostName  
 HAVING MAX(DeliveredDate) IS NULL
```

[image]